# apply a collection of courses to a collection of students

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

I am working with collections of objects and trying to get out of the habit of looping whenever I get to a problem and looking to the API to see if it has already been provided.

I currently have a collection of students and a collection of courses that the students are doing. The courses have a student ID so I could just write a big old for loop that loops around the students, fishes out the courses for each student and stick them in.

```
Dim Students As Generic.List(Of Student)
Dim Courses As Generic.List(Of Course)

For Each s As Student In Students
    s.Courses = Courses.Where(x => x.StudentId == s.StudentId)
Next
```

I Would like to know if this functionality is covered by linq in some form. I'm looking for something like this:

```
Students.*DoSomethingClever(Courses, x => x.StudentId)*
```

I understand that the above might look like nonsense but I hope it conveys what I am trying to achieve.

Alex

Comment: A functionality you're looking for is called: join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something similar

```
Students.ForEach(s => s.Courses = Courses.Where(x => x.StudentId == s.StudentId));
```

you can perform this operation in parallel (only for big collections and only if you have at least two processor cores )

```
Students.AsParallel().ForAll(s=>
{
    s.Courses = Courses.Where(x => x.StudentId == s.StudentId));
});
```

Comment: Thats looking really good! Is there any way to express that in the linq _Students = From s as Student in Students_ style? I have that as a bit of a style running through this process. Sorry if that is a bit cheeky!

Comment: yes you can use `from student in Students.AsParallel() where...`

Comment: Cool, I'll give that a go now!

Answer (score 0):

If by saying **DoSomethingClever** you mean to join data from Courses, please see:

```
Dim JoinedData = From s In Students
                    Join c In Courses
                    On s.StudentId Equals c.StudentId
                    Select StudentName = s.FirstName, CourseName = c.Name
```

For further information: [How to: Combine Data with LINQ by Using Joins (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918093.aspx)